# How to simply excel formula?

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-formula

I have a query that will generate the following formula in an array from SQL and set into a range in worksheet, but it's difficult to read:

`=SUMIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,5)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-6,5)),"+",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-6,COLUMN())))-SUMIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,5)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-6,5)),"-",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-6,COLUMN())))`

So dose excel contain any method to change only the address part `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,5)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-6,5))` to `E10:E5` for easy to trace?

Because of the formula is needed to be dynamic generate before set to worksheet (i.e. dynamic column and row), so it should be needed to simplify after set the array to cell.

Any method can do the similar thing like `Evaluate` function in excel but only apply for `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS` which allow user to read the simply formula like `=SUMIF(E10:E5,"+",J10:J5)-SUMIF(E10:E5,"-",J10:J5)`

Comment: You could probably handle this with some VBA macro changing the inner part of the formula. Have you tried this method?

Comment: if you are after readability, could you calculate `ADDRESS(ROW()-1,5)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-6,5)` in a separate cell, and then substitute that cell into the formula. That way, you would have a visual of `E5:E10` in a cell you can look at

Comment: If you know the cell where you're inserting the formula, and you know the offsets, you can easily just determine the range address by constructing a range object using the starting point and the offsets, and then getting its `Address()`.  If you need the formula to adjust over many rows, then just insert it in one cell and then fill it down.

Comment: My program is a select statement from SQL database of raw data and union some select statement as formula for column summary (which may have 2+ lv summary), so VBA macro may cause performance issue (column count may 30+ and all with column summary)

Comment: @calendarw - well, you can't be sure either way until you try. I don't think there's any "built-in" way to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the formulas, you could enter in RC notation by changing the reference style to `R1C1` or using `.FormulaR1C1`. The advantage of RC notation is that the formula text is consistent down the whole column. For your formula above you could enter either as:

```
=SUMIF(R[-6]C5:R[-1]C5,"+",R[-6]C:R[-1]C)-SUMIF(R[-6]C5:R[-1]C5,"-",R[-6]C:R[-1]C)
```

or `=SUM(SUMIF(R[-6]C5:R[-1]C5,{"+","-"},R[-6]C:R[-1]C)*{1,-1})`

and the formulas should be easy to read in `A1` notation.